# What's wrong with this Dynamic select by JQuery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm trying to make the dynamic select just like this  http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised?view=asciicast
In my case, it won't work somehow.
What's wrong with my code?

**views/registrations/edit.html.erb**

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<% resource.build_user_profile if resource.user_profile.nil? %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>

   <%= devise_error_messages! %>

   <%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>

       <%= profile_form.label :country_id %><br />
       <%= profile_form.collection_select :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>

       <%= profile_form.label :prefecture_id, "State or Prefecture" %><br />
       <%= profile_form.grouped_collection_select :prefecture_id, Country.all, :prefectures, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>   

   <% end %> 

    <br />

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <%= f.submit 'Update', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

**user_profiles.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#user_profile_prefecture_id').parent().hide()
  states = $('#user_profile_prefecture_id').html()
  console.log(prefectures)
  $('#user_profile_country_id').change ->
    country = $('#user_profile_country_id :selected').text()
    escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
    options = $(prefectures).filter("optgroup[label=#{escaped_country}]").html()
    console.log(options)
    if options
      $('#user_profile_prefecture_id').html(options)
      $('#user_profile_prefecture_id').parent().show()      
    else
      $('#user_profile_prefecture_id').empty()
      $('#user_profile_prefecture_id').parent().hide()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case when you pass:

```
<%= f.fields_for :user_profile ... %>
```

field's attributes **name=** and **id=** can not be just "#user_profile...", when parent form builder has an object. To determine exactly ID look at the source code (HTML response).